# How can I access ClusterItem from CustomInfoWindowAdapter?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using marker clustering in my Google Maps Android app, abd have created a `ClusterableItem` class that implements `ClusterItem` as per the implementation guides.

Within this, in addition to the required `position`, `title` and `snippet` variables, I have also declared an additional one that I'd like to store with each marker, as follows:

```
public class ClusterableItem implements ClusterItem {

    private final LatLng position;
    private final String title;
    private final String snippet;

    private final int myNumber;

    public ClusterableItem(double lat, double lng, String title, String snippet, int myNumber) {
        position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        this.title = title;
        this.snippet = snippet;
        this.myNumber = myNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSnippet() {
        return snippet;
    }

    public String getMyNumberAsString() { return String.valueOf(myNumber); }
    public int getMyNumber() { return myNumber; }
}
```

The clustering all works well.

I have also implemented a custom InfoWindow adapter as follows:

```
public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.mInflater = inflater;
    }

    private void setPopupTextContent(Marker marker, View popup) {
        ((TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(marker.getTitle());
        ((TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.snippet)).setText(marker.getSnippet());
    }

    @Override public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        final View popup = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

        setPopupTextContent(marker, popup);
        return popup;
        //return null;
    }

    @Override public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        final View popup = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);
        setPopupTextContent(marker, popup);

        return popup;
    }
```

}

The custom InfoWindow also works as expected.

However, I want to be able to access the `myNumber` value that I have added to the `ClusterItem` to use it in the InfoWindow `setPopupTextContent()` method with something like:

```
        ((TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.myNumberHere)).setText(marker.getMyNumberAsString());
```

Obviously this doesn't work as `getMyNumberAsString()` is a method of `ClusterableItem`, not of `Marker`. And `Marker` cannot be cast as `ClusterableItem` or even `ClusterItem` according to the IDE...

So, is there a way to access this value in my `ClusterableItem` when I only have a reference to the `Marker`?

(I know I could maintain a map of the values associated with the markers somehow, but as this is the only value I need to access and it is simply an `int`, and implemeting a map to track them seems a long way to solve the problem when I can add the value to the proxy object for teh marker.)